# Scrollable div without defined height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have tried to make a scrollable div without a defined height but without success. I want to make the scrollable-menu (left div) match the full view height and still be scrollable.

When I assign a height, the div is scrollable but doesn't match view height, and when I remove the height, the div isn't scrollable but full view height. Here is my current code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 >Header</h1>
    </header>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="scrollable-menu">
       <ul>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}

.scrollable-menu {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 240px;

  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  /* is scrollable but not full height when using defined height like: */
  height: 300px; 
}


.content {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ryj152e/73/

Answer (score 0):

Whoever got the same problem, I finally got it working with those change:

**Adding**

```
ul {
  height: 0px;
}
```

And **removing** the height of scrollable-menu

```
.scrollable-menu {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 240px;

  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```